# PHP login using Array Not DB

Tags: php

As a practice, I am trying to create a script to log a user in using array.

So I have created a associate multidimensional array which holds '`user`' and '`password`',

The idea is to use this array to compare data entered by the user through a HTML form.

The problem I am having is that, the password entered by the user is checked against all the password stored in array not the only one the password belongs to. So I am struggling with a logic to check the password entered by the user with the values stored in array, one by one and not as a whole.

My script:

```
    <?php

$data = Array();

$data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$data['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
$data['passM'] = $_POST['passM'];

$users = Array(
    'tomasz' => '123',
    'mario' => 'abc',

);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$hello='';
    foreach($users as $u => $p){

        if($data['passM'] == $p){
            header("Location: ../home.php");
        }else{
            echo "nooooo";
        }

    }

var_dump($users);

    var_dump($data['email']);
    var_dump($data['pass']);
    var_dump($data['passM']);

}
```

Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: So... why are you checking all the users?

Comment: How do you know what the username is of the person trying to login? i dont see a $_POST['user'];

Comment: Look for these array_key_exists() and in_array()

Comment: Well I am not to sure how to check one by one what I have done is what I know, this is why I am kindly asking for a suggestion how to do it :)

Comment: $_POST['user'] is $_POST['email'] in my case :P I identyfie users by email

Comment: but your storage of username in the array isnt in the e-mail format?

Comment: @Tomazi but you dont have emails in array list. Either make list using emails, or you need to parse email and take first part (before @) if that part is the same as your user names.

Comment: @Tomazi also, if you are just getting started with web development I would get in the habit of encrypting your passwords

Comment: ye its because i am just testing it as soon as it works I will change the usernames with emails within the array :) also yes I will encrypt passwords I am aware of this but it is only I small thing I am playing around with :P

Answer (score 2):

Try This code, I hope you will find answer to your question.

```
$data = Array();

$data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$data['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
$data['passM'] = $_POST['passM'];
 //var_dump($_POST);

$users = Array(
    'tomasz' => '123',
    'mario' => 'abc',

);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$hello='';

    if(in_array($data['passM'],$users)){
      echo "Found";
    }else{
      echo "nooooo";
    }

    }
```

Comment: hey this seems to work well thx but if I want to match 2 things at the same time like the email & password have to both match...?

Comment: Well Mr. Tomari in_array() method look for only value in array. if you  have stored you email in array as value then no issue. check code bellow:

Answer (score 0):

Check the username first, then the pass for these user.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I don't see any logic that provides any way of knowing what user to check against. If you knew what user was logging in you could check that the username of the array was the same as the username the form provided.

```
$data['user'] = $_POST['user'];

foreach($users as $u => $p){
    if($u == $data['user']){
        if($data['passM'] == $p){
            header("Location: ../home.php");
        }else{
            echo "nooooo";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know which user tries to log in.
So, you could just check if this user exists and if the password is correct.

```
$data['user'] = $_POST['user'];
if(array_key_exists($data['user'], $users) && $data['passM'] == $users[$data['user']]) {
    header("Location: ../home.php");
} else {
    echo "nooooo";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Mr. Tomari in_array() method look for only value in array. if you  have stored you email in array as value then no issue. if you have store 'email' as key and 'passm' as value of the that email then you have to use this code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$hello='';

    if(array_key_exists($data['email'],$users) && in_array($data['passM'],$users)){
      echo "Found";
    }else{
      echo "nooooo";
    }

    }
```